# I can't figure out how to enchant armor

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I have Minecraft PE on my iPad,I have an enchantment table,all I can use to enchant my armor is lapis lazuli.

what else can I use to enchant my armor? (I'm not very experienced)

Comment: I also have 15 book shelfs  bye it.

Answer (score 2):

1–3 pieces of Lapis Lazuli are used to enchant items in an enchantment table. The top enchantment slot in the enchantment table will cost you 1 level and 1 piece of Lapis Lazuli; the middle slot will cost you 2 of each and for the bottom enchantment slot, the player will need 3 levels and 3 pieces of Lapis.
This is the only way in which you can enchant items in Minecraft PC and PE.  The fifteen bookshelves that you have will only increase the amount of levels you can use in the enchantment table.

Sources:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli

http://www.minecraft101.net/g/enchanting-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing else you can use besides Lapis Lazuli to enchant items. Lapis Lazuli was never able to be used to enchant things until a version or two ago and it is the only thing you can use right now.